# Constraint formulation for variable cleaning times - MILP optimization

Tags: convex-optimization, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

I have a Mixed Integer Linear Problem where I want to schedule the production of different orders ($O$) in which in each order, there is only one product ($P$) produced.

Each order can be produced once at a time, and between two orders, there is a certain time that has to be scheduled for cleaning the production line. The time depends on which product was produced before, and which product will be produced after. E.g.: if I produce green apple juice and then red apple juice, the cleaning time is set to 20 minutes. However, if grapes juice is produced after green apple juice the time increases to 35 minutes.

I am modeling the production considering the following variables:

- $X_{o, d, h}$ is a binary variable that equals to 1 if the **order o** is produced in the **day d** at the **hour h**, and 0 otherwise.
- $c_{d, h}$ is a binary variable that equals to 1 if the line is being cleaned in the day $d$ at the hour $h$, and 0 otherwise.
- $y_{d, h}$ is a binary variable that equals to 1 if the line not being used (no production nor cleaning) in the day $d$ at the hour $h$, and 0 otherwise.

I also have a matrix $C$ that has the cleaning times between each pair of products. We can also asume to have $C$ for the time to clean between orders, as it is a simple transformation.

I want to create the constraints for the cleaning part. If any order is produced, then cleaning must happen (without stops) for the time specified in matrix $C$, which depends on which product/order that was produced before, and which product/order was produced after.

I got to formulate the mandatory start of cleaning by adding these constraints:

$$c_{d,h} \geq x_{o,d,h-1} - x_{o,d,h}$$
$$x_{o,d,h} + c_{d,h} + y_{d,h} = 1$$

However, this just makes one block of cleaning, and there have to be as many blocks as refered to matrix $C$, which depends on which product was produced before and which product is produced after. Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: Must each product be produced exactly once?

Comment: Yes, that’s a good point. In fact, the problem is about producing orders that should be produced once and each order has just one product. I tried to simplify it. But we can assume in this example each product is produced just once

Comment: I updated the text to reflect this reality :)

Comment: This is an instance of a production problem with "sequence-dependent setup times", which has been heavily studied. Try searching using that phrase, and I'm pretty sure you will find published MILP models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can model this as an asymmetric traveling salesman problem (ATSP) with a dummy depot node, a node for each order, and $C$ as the arc cost matrix. Arcs to and from the depot have zero cost.  See https://communities.sas.com/t5/Mathematical-Optimization/Job-Shop-Scheduling-Problem/m-p/783190

For a compact MILP formulation, search for Miller-Tucker-Zemlin (MTZ).

Comment: Thank you for answer! I didn't finish to formulate it yet but it does a lot of sense to me. So basically, by adding a binary variable s_{i,j} which represents if the order j follows order i, ensuring that each order is only produced once, adding a new natural number variable u_{j} which represents the position of order j in the production and adding the MTZ constraint: u_{i} - u_{j} + (n+1)*s_{i,j} <= n-2, being n the total number of visited orders, this should work right?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.